# javascript put value in code string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have a code like string.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var code = "var y1=400; \n\
            update : function(data)    { \n\
            var x1 = 10;\n\
            var x2 = 20;\n\
   }";
```

I should put   some value in body of update  function, but befor x1. I wanna put `var x0 = 0;`  in body of function.  I wrote one solution,

```
 var parse_str = "update : function(data) {";
                    var position = code.indexOf(parse_str);
                    var tmp_str = parse_str.length;
                    var tmp_num = tmp_str.length;

                    code = code.substr(0, position + tmp_str) + "var x0 = 0;" + code.substr(position + tmp_str);
```

but this way is very  bad solution. It is depends on numder of space elemenst in string like "`update : function(data) {`".  Please help me to find other solution. This solution is bad, because we depend on spaces in "`update : function(data) {`" between parenthesis.

Comment: Why is your javascript in a string?

Comment: it is data from log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
code = code.replace(/update[^{]+?{/, function(s){ return s + 'var x0 = 0;'});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfb7s/)

Comment: no, it is wrong way! It is not working. For example
`var code = "var y1=400; \n\
update : function(data) \n\
{ \n\
            var x1 = 10;\n\
            var x2 = 20;\n\
   }";`